# Kotlin - "Don't care" in desugaring of data class

Tags: wildcard, kotlin, syntactic-sugar

Is it possible to mark "don't cares" in Kotlin? I have not been able to find the appropriate syntax, Haskell and Python use the `_` symbol but this does not work in Kotlin.

Example,

```
data class DesugarExample(val foo: Int, val bar: Int, val baz: Int)

fun desugarIt() {
  val (useFoo, dontCare, useBaz) = DesugarExample(1, 2, 3)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't currently possible, [but according to Dmitry Jemerov](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/04/kotlin-post-1-0-roadmap/#comment-41992), the use of the underscore in this use case is planned for Kotlin 1.1.

**Update**: The example above does in fact work in Kotlin 1.1 when replacing one of the vals with underscore to indicate "don't care". Example:

```
fun desugarIt() {
    val (useFoo, dontCare, _) = DesugarExample(1, 2, 3)
}
```

Comment: The feature was implemented and will be included in 1.1-M3.